# backbone events not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to manually trigger a click event right after the html has been rendered but it's not working.

To simplify and verify that it's not working I tried this code:

```
var _testView = Backbone.View.extend({

   events : {
    'click a' : 'sayHi'
   },

   initialize : function() {
    this.render();
    this.$el.find('a').trigger('click');
   },

   render : function() {
    $(document.body).html(
        this.$el.html('<a href="#">alert hi</a>')
    );
   },

   sayHi : function() {
    alert('Hi');
    return false;
   }

});

var y = new _testView;
```

I'm trying to manually trigger the click event but it's not being triggered. If I'm going to put the trigger in a setTimeout with a delay of 500 it will work. I don't know why.... thx

Comment: Is there any special reason why are you triggering the click and not calling the ,,sayHi" function?

Comment: to my real project - the anchor that triggers the click has a DOM attribute that is part of the method's logic. that's why it's relying on the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I looked at the Backbone core and I see that initialize method is being called first before attaching the events to the view.

```
View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    this._configure(options || {});
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.delegateEvents();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the click event on the element which haven't been yet created. You should call the function when the render is finished or you can just call this.sayHi() instead of triggering the click.

Answer (score -1):

hjuster is correct.  the $(document.body) wait for the 'document ready' event, and you are calling new _testView before the document is ready.  You can change your intialize to this - it queues up the trigger to execute after the document is ready.

```
initialize : function() {
    this.render();
    var self = this;   
    $(function(){
        self.$el.find('a').trigger('click');
    });
},
```

I added the var 'self' since you can't reference 'this' to get your _testView object in the function.

It works [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neillamoureux/NJTmB/4/)